# how can I set permissions to a batch file mkdir creation

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to set up a backup tool for users so they can backup their files to a network share. I am having a little difficulty and can't seem to find the answer. Everything works in my script so far except one part, setting the permissions to the files past the ones I made on the share. Here is my script so far:

```
mkdir \\fileserver\users\%username%\%computername%\  
mkdir \\fileserver\users\%username%\%computername%\Desktop\  
mkdir \\fileserver\users\%username%\%computername%\My_Documents\  
mkdir \\fileserver\users\%username%\%computername%\Favorites\  
@cls  
@echo Company Name - :Sync: Full :  
@echo For support, please call IS at ext. ####  
@echo --------------------------------------------------------------  
@echo Press any key to start the synchronization of your "Desktop",  
@echo "Favorites", and "My Documents" folder to a network server.  
@echo --------------------------------------------------------------  
@echo This will NOT include any virtual machines, music files, or   
@echo video files located in these areas.  
@pause  
robocopy "C:\users\%username%\Desktop" \\fileserver\users\%username%\%computername%\Desktop\ /s /xf *.avi *.iso *.mp3 *.m4a *.m4b *.m4p *.m4v *.mp4 *.ova*.vmdk*.vmem *.vmss *.vhd *.wma *.wmv *.pst *.bak *.epub *.ipa *.mobi*.mov *.rdp /purge  
robocopy "C:\users\%username%\My Documents" \\fileserver\users\%username%\%computername%\My_Documents\ /s /xf *.avi *.iso *.mp3 *.m4a *.m4b *.m4p *.m4v *.mp4 *.ova *.vmdk *.vmem *.vmss *.vhd *.wma *.wmv *.pst *.bak *.epub *.ipa *.mobi *.mov *.rdp /purge  
robocopy "C:\users\%username%\Favorites" \\fileserver\users\%username%\%computername%\Favorites\ /s /xf *.avi *.iso *.mp3 *.m4a *.m4b *.m4p *.m4v *.mp4 *.ova *.vmdk *.vmem *.vmss *.vhd *.wma *.wmv *.pst *.bak *.epub *.ipa *.mobi *.mov *.rdp /purge  
@pause
```

I have created on the network share everything up to \fileserver\users\ with the script building out the username and computername when it is run for the computer its run on.

Where I run into my problem is after the Robocopy runs it cant see the new folders made by the previous command at the beginning of my script. I think this is as a result of permissions not being given to the newly created folders.
Is this correct or is there another issue I just don't see?
Do I need a flag in the mkdir command, if so where and what?
Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: 1. The posted code creates the directories on `\\fileserver` but `robocopy` copies to `\\DC-FS1`. 2. To manually set the permission [icacls](http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html) is needed

Comment: Hmm... I'm nit sure whether `mkdir` supports UNC paths; maybe `pushd`/`popd` could help...

Comment: the UNC paths are supported, just tested it on Win7.

Comment: I meant to change \\DC-FS1 to \\fileserver for anonymity sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

icacls worked perfect for setting the permissions I needed to be able to write to the new files created. Thank you wOxxOm for the tip. Now my script has posed a whole new problem. Off to look at that.